# Como removo e substituo arquivos da branch master por arquivos de uma outra branch? (GitHub)

Tags: git, github

Caros, minha dúvida é a seguinte:

Eu precisei baixar um projeto em outra máquina, então fiz um clone no GitHub para tal, porém, eu mudei toda a estrutura dos arquivos, e queria subir para a branch master com essa nova estrutura e seus respectivos arquivos, minha solução até o momento foi fazer o push em uma branch secundária, mas gostaria de deixar tudo na master, mesmo que remova os arquivos antigos para isso.

Comecei a usar git recentemente, perdão pela 'cabaçada' XD.

Comment: Se você já subiu os arquivos do seu servidor local para uma branch não master, agora no git é só fazer um new pull request.

Comment: Quando tento fazer o "pull request" o GitHub me retorna a seguinte mensagem: "There isn’t anything to compare."

Comment: @smourao, sim, subi em outra branch, porém, quando clico para fazer o pull request dentro do GitHub, ele só aparece essa mensagem _"There isn’t anything to compare."_.

Comment: já tentou `git push --force` ou `git push --force-with-lease`?

Comment: @tvdias funcionou! Deu certo utilizando o _git push --force origin master_ :) muito obrigado!

Comment: adicionei como resposta :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como explicado na pergunta, onde o objetivo é substituir o código de `origin/master` com o conteúdo da branch local, pode-se fazer `git push --force` ou `git push --force-with-lease`.

Obs: O uso dssa operação é desencorajado. Entretanto o AP afirma que o repositório é privado e ele é o único contribuidor e deseja "ignorar" o que está no repositório remoto. Neste caso, não vejo problemas em usar o `--force`.

Mais informações sobre o assunto podem ser encontradas nesta outra pergunta no SO (em inglês): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21259585/other-consequences-of-git-push-force

Answer (score 0):

Dê uma pesquisada sobre *merge*.

Você precisará de algo como ***git merge [nome branch]*** para enviar todos os arquivos para a sua branch master.

Comment: Dei uma lida em um artigo que falava sobre o _merge_ e o _rebase_, fiz os processos corretamente, porém na hora de fazer o push para a master acontece o seguinte erro:
_! [rejected]          master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/x/yy'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details._

Comment: @MateusDaniel, pelo que está dizendo na mensagem, provavelmente você não está com os arquivos do seu computador como os do repositório na nuvem.

Tente fazer o Git Pull, verifique se não terá conflitos, e então faça o push/merge.

PS: Não sou expert em git, mas to tentando ajudar rs

Comment: @G Orlando não tem problema, estamos aqui para nos ajudar rsrs .. então, tentei dar um pull também e fazer o push depois, porém sem sucesso também. Se não tiver jeito, vou deixar na outra branch mesmo.